# Prevent myself from writing to files in directory I have read/write access to?

Tags: windows-7

I asked for access to a very important directory on a file server that is maintained and controlled by another department.  I was given read/write access instead of read-only access.  It may take awhile to get an administrator to change it to read-only.  In the meantime, is there any way I can prevent myself from modifying/deleting all files in this directory?

I'm in a corporate environment using Windows 7 enterprise.  I do not have administrative rights on my computer.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around this - just be careful!

Answer (score 1):

Couple/few ideas:

1. Make a backup of any/all files before you touch any of them.
2. Copy the file(s) you want to read to your computer first, that way you're not touching the shared files while reading them.
3. Check to see if [previous versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7) are enabled on the server for that share.  If so, worry about it less.
4. Pay (extra) attention to what you're doing, and take your chances.
5. Don't touch and of the files until they adjust your access.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

- map the important drive to one of your machine's drive letters
- share *that* drive letter to *yourself*
- set the permissions for the share to readonly
- map that share to a new drive-letter
- work in the remapped drive (which should be non-writable by you)

Agreeing with the other answers of course.

Further reading:

- [Default Permissions for Shared Folders Is Read-Only Access for Everyone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/328065)
- [How to Change Shared Folder Permissions in Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-change-shared-folder-permissions-in-window0.html)
- [Use NET USE to mount a network drive as read only](https://serverfault.com/questions/280747/use-net-use-to-mount-a-network-drive-as-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions that you can do. I'm not really familiar with Windows Server, or if you're even using Windows Server that's not really clear to me. No matter what operating system you're working on I'm sure this could work.

My first suggestion is, you can move the file from the server to your computer ,work on it from your computer so if you make a wrong edit it won't save onto the server automatically. If you're running a Linux server, then you can use the secure copy command to a MacBook then take the file from the MacBook with a USB Drive and put it on your computer.

My second suggestion is, you can go to the properties of the file and to privacy. And make it a read only file. I don't think you need administrator privileges to do that. 
Again maybe you should make a copy of the file somewhere else on the server so won't need to worry about actually disrupting the file.